# Calling individual data from multidimensional array

Tags: php

Trying to clean up code by using categories to determine output. Not sure how to call an individual entry of a multidimensional array.

Array:

```
$category = [
    '1' => [
        'market' => 'Designing',
        'icon' => 'palette'],
    '2' => [
        'market' => 'Developing',
        'icon' => 'code'],
    '3' => [
        'market' => 'Editing',
        'icon' => 'film'],
    '4' => [
        'market' => 'Marketing',
        'icon' => 'chart-line'],
    '5' => [
        'market' => 'Translating',
        'icon' => 'comments'],
    '6' => [
        'market' => 'Writing',
        'icon' => 'marker']
        ];
```

Grabbing INT from database to attempt to change out the icon.
In this example $task['category'] = 1, so ideally the icon should change to palette. Where am I going wrong here?

```
<td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-<?php if ($task['category'] == $category()) { echo $category['icon']; } else { echo "code"; }?>"></i></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use your db value since you want to use it as the "index" of your array like :

```
echo $category[$task['category']]['icon'];
```

This will be converted to `$category[1]['icon']` which is what you want to display. So you can skip the if.

A full example:

```
$category = [
    '1' => [
        'market' => 'Designing',
        'icon' => 'palette'],
    '2' => [
        'market' => 'Developing',
        'icon' => 'code'],
    '3' => [
        'market' => 'Editing',
        'icon' => 'film'],
    '4' => [
        'market' => 'Marketing',
        'icon' => 'chart-line'],
    '5' => [
        'market' => 'Translating',
        'icon' => 'comments'],
    '6' => [
        'market' => 'Writing',
        'icon' => 'marker']
        ];


$task['category'] = 1;


if(isset($category[$task['category']]))
{
  echo $category[$task['category']]['icon'];
}
else
{
  echo 'not found';
}
```

The output will be *palette*.

The `if-else` is there to handle the possibility that the value from your database does not match any of your array keys so you have a fallback. If that's not the case you can remove it.

Comment: Right, I completely forgot the array structure with the number in the middle. Works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this bit here:

```php
if ($task['category'] == $category()) { echo $category['icon']; } else { echo "code"; }
```

I think `$category` is a variable, but you're trying to run it as a function (unless you're using it as a [variable function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)). and in that case, that variable function name will collide with this array. If You'd like to get the value of `$category['1']['icon']` from `$task['category']` value, then you may have to call it like this:

```php
if ($task['category'] == someValue()) { echo $category[$task['category']]['icon']; } else { echo "code"; }
```

or if you have that `someValue()` function returning you the value, you can use that too:

```php
if ($task['category'] == someValue()) { echo $category[someValue()]]['icon']; } else { echo "code"; }
```